# Remove group headers and move elements while looping through nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services, xslt-1.0

**XML INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <InvNum>
        <InvNum>10001</InvNum>
        <BatchNumber>
            <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
            <SeqNumber>
                <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>122223</a>
                    <b>111</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </SeqNumber>
        </BatchNumber>
    </InvNum>
    <InvNum>
        <InvNum>10002</InvNum>
        <BatchNumber>
            <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
            <SeqNumber>
                <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>123</a>
                    <b>456</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>33</a>
                    <b>99</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </SeqNumber>
        </BatchNumber>
    </InvNum>
</data>
```

**Desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<data>
    <Invoice>
        <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
        <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
        <InvNum>10001</InvNum>
        <InvoiceItem>
            <a>122223</a>
            <b>111</b>
        </InvoiceItem>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
        <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
        <InvNum>10002</InvNum>
        <InvoiceItem>
            <a>123</a>
            <b>456</b>
        </InvoiceItem>
        <InvoiceItem>
            <a>33</a>
            <b>99</b>
        </InvoiceItem>
    </Invoice>
</data>
```

**This is my XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rpt="Invoice">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--suppress group and detail_collection-->
    <xsl:template match="rpt:Detail_Collection|rpt:BatchNumber_Collection|rpt:SeqNumber_Collection|rpt:InvNum_Collection">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--end suppress all group collection-->
    <!-- create node for Invoice and copy child nodes to it-->
    <xsl:template match="rpt:InvNum">
        <xsl:element name="InvoiceNumber">
            <xsl:element name="BatchNumber">
                <xsl:value-of select="//rpt:BatchNumber/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="SeqNumber">
                <xsl:value-of select="//rpt:SeqNumber/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="InvNum">
                <xsl:value-of select="rpt:InvNum/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="SUBCHILDS"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="rpt:InvoiceItem" name="SUBCHILDS">
        <xsl:element name="InvoiceItem">
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:value-of select="//a"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="b">
                <xsl:value-of select="//b"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using SSRS and exporting data to XML using XSLT to get the desired output. 
I need to remove the group headers like BatchNumber and Seqnumber but show its value and move Invnum element down the order. With my xsl, I am getting only first record. It is not not able to loop through the nodes to the next records. 
Any help in pointing the issue or fixing this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have already shared the XSL stylesheet that I tried....Output looked ok with it but it did not show all records but just the first one. So I am guessing it did not loop through as needed.

Comment: I am sorry, because of the misformat I did not see it. I formatted your question correctly now. I noticed your provided XML files where not well-formed because of a missing root tag. I have added the root tag `<data>`, maybe you can correct it to the root tag it really needs to be?

Comment: MarkVeenstra has given you a good answer, but the reason why your code may not have been working was your were doing `<xsl:value-of select="//rpt:BatchNumber/text()"/>` when you should have been doing `<xsl:value-of select=".//rpt:BatchNumber/text()"/>`. Without the full stop, you are always getting the first `rpt:BatchNumber` relative to the document node. The full stop means you get it relative to the current node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created **additional nodes** before `InvoiceItem` in the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <InvNum>
        <InvNum>10001</InvNum>
        <BatchNumber>
            <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
            <SeqNumber>
                <add>ADDITIONAL NODE1</add>
                <add>ADDITIONAL NODE2</add>
                <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>122223</a>
                    <b>111</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </SeqNumber>
        </BatchNumber>
    </InvNum>
    <InvNum>
        <InvNum>10002</InvNum>
        <BatchNumber>
            <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
            <SeqNumber>
                <add>ADDITIONAL NODE3</add>
                <add>ADDITIONAL NODE4</add>
                <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>123</a>
                    <b>456</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
                <InvoiceItem>
                    <a>33</a>
                    <b>99</b>
                </InvoiceItem>
            </SeqNumber>
        </BatchNumber>
    </InvNum>
</data>
```

using the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:rpt="Invoice" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="rpt">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data/InvNum">
        <Invoice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="BatchNumber/BatchNumber"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="BatchNumber/SeqNumber/SeqNumber"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="InvNum"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="BatchNumber/SeqNumber"/>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="InvNum/BatchNumber">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="BatchNumber/SeqNumber">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SeqNumber)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <Invoice>
      <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
      <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
      <InvNum>10001</InvNum>
      <add>ADDITIONAL NODE1</add>
      <add>ADDITIONAL NODE2</add>
      <InvoiceItem>
         <a>122223</a>
         <b>111</b>
      </InvoiceItem>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <BatchNumber>201400013002</BatchNumber>
      <SeqNumber>2</SeqNumber>
      <InvNum>10002</InvNum>
      <add>ADDITIONAL NODE3</add>
      <add>ADDITIONAL NODE4</add>
      <InvoiceItem>
         <a>123</a>
         <b>456</b>
      </InvoiceItem>
      <InvoiceItem>
         <a>33</a>
         <b>99</b>
      </InvoiceItem>
   </Invoice>
</data>
```

Comment: This was the breakthrough for me. <xsl:template match="BatchNumber/SeqNumber">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SeqNumber)]"/>
    </xsl:template>
I used it for all header elements. Though involved lengthy work it was worth. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but the next XSLT does the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rpt="Invoice" xmlns="Invoice" exclude-result-prefixes="rpt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rpt:InvNum[child::rpt:InvNum]">
        <Invoice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rpt:BatchNumber/rpt:BatchNumber" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rpt:BatchNumber/rpt:SeqNumber/rpt:SeqNumber" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rpt:InvNum" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rpt:BatchNumber/rpt:SeqNumber/rpt:InvoiceItem" />
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried Mark's suggestion-but InvoiceItem node that had subchilds did not come up.   Also tried adding 'dot' to my existing template and it worked for outer elements but again got only first InvoiceItem not other records.

Comment: I am testing with just a few nodes. But in real scenario, there are many more nodes before InvoiceItem so using the template as given by Mark does not seem practical. Is there any other alternative to it ?

Comment: @user3443653 If you do not explain the _real_ scenario you're effectively wasting people's time. If you reduce the complexity of your input XML make sure you preserve the _problem_ you are facing.